# SQL: From a group by get another column on max date

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

So I have a table more less like this name it **tests_summary**:

| test_id | completed | remaining | score_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | 6 | 1 | 2022-05-02 |
| 200 | 2 | 7 | 2022-05-01 |
| 200 | 5 | 10 | 2022-04-29 |
| 200 | 5 | 15 | 2022-04-28 |
| 199 | 10 | 0 | 2022-05-02 |
| 199 | 2 | 10 | 2022-05-01 |

First I tried to group by each test_id, SUM every completed by each test, but I want to get in the remaining column, the remaining value in the most recent score date.
Example test_id 200, **the most recent date is 2022-05-02, and 1 is remaining** that is the value I want. In this table is already ordered but in my real table is not. 
**Expected result**

| test_id | completed | remaining |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | 18 | 1 |
| 199 | 12 | 0 |

**version 5.7.12**

Comment: Can you tag your DBMS, and its version please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)

Answer (score 0):

You can use row number function to give you a 1 for every item you care about.

Note, I use * here as a shorthand but you should only select the columns you are interested in, in your final code.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT z.*, ROW_NUMBER(PARTITION BY test_id ORDER BY score_date DESC) AS RN
  FROM sometableyoudidnotname z
) X
WHERE X.RN = 1
```

Comment: Not in my current mysql version RowNumber

Comment: what sql are you using @JosuéArreola?

Comment: row_number has been in mysql since version 8 -- about 4 years ago

Comment: 5.7.12 is my version

Comment: @JosuéArreola -- that was released in 2015 -- might want to consider an upgrade (5.x will be supported till oct 23)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```sql
SELECT test_id, completed, remaining
  FROM (SELECT test_id,
               remaining,
               SUM(completed) OVER(PARTITION BY test_id) AS completed,               
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY test_id ORDER BY score_date DESC) AS rn
          FROM t) tt
 WHERE rn = 1
```

where you can get the latest date through descendingly sorted by the `score_date` while partitioning by `test_id` in order to group by each of them provided that your database and its version is suitable to use a window(or analytic) function

Comment: ROW_NUMBER not in my version

Answer (score 0):

**Upd.** That solution for PostgreSQL only. Thanks [Hogan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215752/hogan) for correcting me

I'm not sure that my solution will be the most optimal for performance, but nevertheless it works.
The main idea is to use the **DISTINCT ON** construct on the "remaining" column and separately summarize the "completed" column with a subquery:

```
WITH
    t AS (SELECT 200                AS test_id,
                 0                  AS completed,
                 1                  AS remaining,
                 '2022-05-02'::DATE AS score_date
          UNION
          SELECT 200,
                 2,
                 3,
                 '2022-05-01'
          UNION
          SELECT 199,
                 10,
                 0,
                 '2022-05-02'
          UNION
          SELECT 199,
                 2,
                 10,
                 '2022-05-01')
SELECT
    distinct on (t1.test_id)
        t1.remaining,
        t1.test_id,
        (select sum(completed) from t where t.test_id = t1.test_id)
    FROM t t1
ORDER BY t1.test_id,t1.score_date desc;
```

[output result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5dtH.png)

Comment: They only want the most recent date

Comment: yup, if you add "t1.score_date" at the end of my select block, you'll get score_date = '2022-05-02' for both lines. Coz we use DISTINCT ON ... ORDER BY date DESC construction

Comment: oh right -- this is a progres only feature.  Why di you think they are using that platform?

Comment: Damn, that's my mistake, you're right. I'll add this point to my comment, maybe it will help someone with a similar question in PG.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. What if there are thousands of days for the same test_id ?

Comment: I updated the post, in order to give it more clarity on what I want to achieve.